# anacron does not execute my bash script

Tags: linux, cron

For testing I wrote this bash script

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Time: $(date)" >> /home/benno/Desktop/anacron
```

which I want to execute with anacron on a daily basis.
I therefore added the following line to my `/etc/anacrontab` file

```
1       0      benno                    /home/benno/Desktop/anacronCheck.sh
```

However, when I run the command `anacron -n` (running all jobs without time delay) nothing happens.

Any suggestions why anacron is not running my bash script?

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/benno/Desktop/anacronCheck.sh` manually?

Comment: the script is executed and the time is written to the file named ancron

Comment: Does anacron have a (error) log file?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, what went wrong was that you should run anacon -n with root permissions (i.e. with sudo). By default anacron forks to the background, you can prevent this by the option -d -> this way the permission error got printed to the console...

Comment: please write your solution as an answer and after the allotted time (48 hrs?), accept your own answer to gain valuable reputation points. You might also want to look at melpomene's answers and upvote one to show your appreciation ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: can I move the question there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to run anacron via the following command

```
sudo anacron -fdn
```

anacron needs root privileges otherwise it wont do anything, hence `sudo`.
The -f and -n parameter together force all jobs to be executed immediately disregarding of timestamps and delays. -d prevents anacron from forking into the background -> error messages will otherwise not be printed to the console.

Comment: I know the question is old, but I'm getting the same permissions error. Running it with root privilege *does* work, but how do you get it to run automatically (preferably without `sudo`)?